# Why String class doesn't have a TYPE field?

Tags: java

In Java, if I want to get `Class` object, I can use TYPE attribute.

For example:

```
Class<?> clazz = Boolean.TYPE;
```

By why `String` class doesn't have a **TYPE** field ?

Comment: The type of any class is "type".class.  For example, `String.class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String doesn't have it because `String` doesn't need it: it would just be exactly the same as `String.class`, which is just as easy to get to.  The difference is that `Boolean.TYPE` is not the same as `Boolean.class`, but rather `boolean.class`; the wrapper class is different from the primitive.

Comment: Where would this be used?

Comment: Honestly, there's not much use for it: you might as well just write `boolean.class`, which you could use wherever you'd use a `Class<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

TYPE attribute represents the primitive type `boolean` in `Boolean` class. But `String` does not have a primitive type. You can use `getClass()` method on any class to get the class object.
Refer
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TYPE

Answer (score 1):

The **TYPE** static member variable is not available for `String` class as it's not a wrapper class.

Basically, it is used to return class instance for a particular primitive type class.

For example :

```
Class<?> clazz = Boolean.TYPE; // (Class<Boolean>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("boolean");
```

So, you can't do `String.TYPE` as it's not there.

You can do simply : `Class<?> clazz = String.class;`